# Does latest mail clients support Inline Image Embedding?

Tags: php, html, email

I wanted to show an Image in an Email. Embedded image into HTML email message with image tag something like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..." width="32" height="32">
```

and sent email using **PHP** `mail()`. As a result; Email Received only with Text and couldn't see any image in **Outlook 2010** and as well in **Gmail**. After googling found website [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email) mentioning some test results across various mail clients. Are these results true? 
What are the other ways to Show Images inline with **HTML** email using **PHP**?

**UPDATE:**

*Actual Source Code*

```
                <?php ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
            error_reporting( E_ALL );

            if(isset($_POST['emailadd'])){

                #controller
                $mailNotification = new mailNotification();
                if(isset($_POST['emailadd'])){
                    $mailNotification->set_To($_POST['emailadd']);
                }
                $mailNotification->set_From('teest@dfsfdsfs.com');
                $mailNotification->set_subject('PHP Mail Test script');
                $mailNotification->set_username('User Name');
                $mailNotification->set_message_heading('Claim Draft Posted for Approval.');
                $mailNotification->set_message('Phasellus dictum sapien a neque luctus cursus. Pellentesque sem dolor, fringilla et pharetra vitaea.');
                $mailNotification->set_panel_message('6 Claims, 1 Travel Request Sent for Processing. Check Status by Logging into System. <a href="#">Log In! &raquo;</a>');
                $mailNotification->sendmail();

                #view
                echo $mailNotification->_sendmail_response;

            }else{ ?>
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <label for="emailadd">Recipient Email Address: </label><input id="emailadd" type="text" name="emailadd" />
                </form>
            <?php }
            # model class
            class mailNotification{
                function set_DTD($dtd){
                    $this->_DTD=$dtd;
                }
                function get_DTD(){
                    if(!isset($this->_DTD)){ return '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'; }
                    else{ return $this->_DTD; }
                }
                function set_header($mailheader){
                    $this->_header=$mailheader;
                }
                function get_header(){
                    if(isset($this->_header)){ return $this->_header; }
                    else{
                        $this->_header = "From:" . $this->_from. "\r\n";
                        if(isset($this->_reply_to)){ $this->_header .= "Reply-To: ". $this->_reply_to. "\r\n"; }
                        if(isset($this->_cc)){ $this->_header .= "CC: ".$this->_cc."\r\n"; }
                        $this->_header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                        $this->_header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                        $this->_header .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
                        $this->_header .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
                        return $this->_header;
                    }
                }
                function set_From($fromemail){
                    $this->_from=$fromemail;
                }
                function set_To($toemail){
                    $this->_to=$toemail;
                }
                function set_Cc($ccemail){
                    $this->_cc=$ccemail;
                }
                function set_Reply_To($rplytoemail){
                    $this->_reply_to=$rplytoemail;
                }
                function set_subject($mailsubject){
                    $this->_subject=$mailsubject;
                }
                function set_username($username){
                    $this->_username=$username;
                }
                function set_message_heading($msgheading){
                    $this->_message_heading=$msgheading;
                }
                function set_message($message){
                    $this->_message=$message;
                }
                function set_panel_message($panelmsg){
                    $this->_panel_message=$panelmsg;
                }
                function set_footer_right_message($footrightmsg){
                    $this->_footer_right_message=$footrightmsg;
                }
                function get_footer_right_message(){
                    if(!isset($this->_footer_right_message)){ return '<table class="six columns"><tr><td class="last right-text-pad"><h5>Processed by:</h5><p>Phone: 408.341.0600</p><p>Email: <a href="mailto:sdfsdf@uiouiouio.com">sdfsdf@uiouiouio.com</a></p></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table>'; }
                    else{ return $this->_footer_right_message; }
                }
                function set_footer_left_message($footleftmsg){
                    $this->_footer_left_message=$footleftmsg;
                }
                function get_footer_left_message(){
                    if(!isset($this->_footer_left_message)){ return '<!--<h5>Connect With Us:</h5><table class="tiny-button facebook"><tr><td><a href="#">Facebook</a></td></tr></table><br><table class="tiny-button twitter"><tr><td><a href="#">Twitter</a></td></tr></table><br><table class="tiny-button google-plus"><tr><td><a href="#">Google +</a></td></tr></table></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table>-->'; }
                    else{ return $this->_footer_left_message; }
                }
                function set_footer($footer){
                    $this->_footer=$footer;
                }
                function get_footer(){
                    if(!isset($this->_footer)){ return '<a href="#">Terms</a> | <a href="#">Privacy</a> | <a href="#">Unsubscribe</a>'; }
                    else{ return $this->_footer; }
                }
                function get_message_body(){
                    return $this->_message_body= $this->get_DTD().'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
                <style>
            #outlook a { 
              padding:0; 
            } 
            body{ 
              width:100% !important; 
              min-width: 100%;
              -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; 
              -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; 
              margin:0; 
              padding:0;
            }
            .ExternalClass { 
              width:100%;
            } 
            .ExternalClass, 
            .ExternalClass p, 
            .ExternalClass span, 
            .ExternalClass font, 
            .ExternalClass td, 
            .ExternalClass div { 
              line-height: 100%; 
            } 
            #backgroundTable { 
              margin:0; 
              padding:0; 
              width:100% !important; 
              line-height: 100% !important; 
            }
            img { 
              outline:none; 
              text-decoration:none; 
              -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
              width: auto;
              max-width: 100%; 
              float: left; 
              clear: both; 
              display: block;
            }
            center {
              width: 100%;
              min-width: 580px;
            }
            a img { 
              border: none;
            }
            p {
              margin: 0 0 0 10px;
            }
            table {
              border-spacing: 0;
              border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td { 
              word-break: break-word;
              -webkit-hyphens: auto;
              -moz-hyphens: auto;
              hyphens: auto;
              border-collapse: collapse !important; 
            }
            table, tr, td {
              padding: 0;
              vertical-align: top;
              text-align: left;
            }
            hr {
              color: #d9d9d9; 
              background-color: #d9d9d9; 
              height: 1px; 
              border: none;
            }
            table.body {
              height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
            }
            table.container {
              width: 580px;
              margin: 0 auto;
              text-align: inherit;
            }
            table.row { 
              padding: 0px; 
              width: 100%;
              position: relative;
            }
            table.container table.row {
              display: block;
            }
            td.wrapper {
              padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
              position: relative;
            }
            table.columns,
            table.column {
              margin: 0 auto;
            }
            table.columns td,
            table.column td {
              padding: 0px 0px 10px; 
            }
            table.columns td.sub-columns,
            table.column td.sub-columns,
            table.columns td.sub-column,
            table.column td.sub-column {
              padding-right: 10px;
            }
            td.sub-column, td.sub-columns {
              min-width: 0px;
            }
            table.row td.last,
            table.container td.last {
              padding-right: 0px;
            }
            table.one { width: 30px; }
            table.two { width: 80px; }
            table.three { width: 130px; }
            table.four { width: 180px; }
            table.five { width: 230px; }
            table.six { width: 280px; }
            table.seven { width: 330px; }
            table.eight { width: 380px; }
            table.nine { width: 430px; }
            table.ten { width: 480px; }
            table.eleven { width: 530px; }
            table.twelve { width: 580px; }
            table.one center { min-width: 30px; }
            table.two center { min-width: 80px; }
            table.three center { min-width: 130px; }
            table.four center { min-width: 180px; }
            table.five center { min-width: 230px; }
            table.six center { min-width: 280px; }
            table.seven center { min-width: 330px; }
            table.eight center { min-width: 380px; }
            table.nine center { min-width: 430px; }
            table.ten center { min-width: 480px; }
            table.eleven center { min-width: 530px; }
            table.twelve center { min-width: 580px; }
            table.one .panel center { min-width: 10px; }
            table.two .panel center { min-width: 60px; }
            table.three .panel center { min-width: 110px; }
            table.four .panel center { min-width: 160px; }
            table.five .panel center { min-width: 210px; }
            table.six .panel center { min-width: 260px; }
            table.seven .panel center { min-width: 310px; }
            table.eight .panel center { min-width: 360px; }
            table.nine .panel center { min-width: 410px; }
            table.ten .panel center { min-width: 460px; }
            table.eleven .panel center { min-width: 510px; }
            table.twelve .panel center { min-width: 560px; }
            .body .columns td.one,
            .body .column td.one { width: 8.333333%; }
            .body .columns td.two,
            .body .column td.two { width: 16.666666%; }
            .body .columns td.three,
            .body .column td.three { width: 25%; }
            .body .columns td.four,
            .body .column td.four { width: 33.333333%; }
            .body .columns td.five,
            .body .column td.five { width: 41.666666%; }
            .body .columns td.six,
            .body .column td.six { width: 50%; }
            .body .columns td.seven,
            .body .column td.seven { width: 58.333333%; }
            .body .columns td.eight,
            .body .column td.eight { width: 66.666666%; }
            .body .columns td.nine,
            .body .column td.nine { width: 75%; }
            .body .columns td.ten,
            .body .column td.ten { width: 83.333333%; }
            .body .columns td.eleven,
            .body .column td.eleven { width: 91.666666%; }
            .body .columns td.twelve,
            .body .column td.twelve { width: 100%; }
            td.offset-by-one { padding-left: 50px; }
            td.offset-by-two { padding-left: 100px; }
            td.offset-by-three { padding-left: 150px; }
            td.offset-by-four { padding-left: 200px; }
            td.offset-by-five { padding-left: 250px; }
            td.offset-by-six { padding-left: 300px; }
            td.offset-by-seven { padding-left: 350px; }
            td.offset-by-eight { padding-left: 400px; }
            td.offset-by-nine { padding-left: 450px; }
            td.offset-by-ten { padding-left: 500px; }
            td.offset-by-eleven { padding-left: 550px; }
            td.expander {
              visibility: hidden;
              width: 0px;
              padding: 0 !important;
            }
            table.columns .text-pad,
            table.column .text-pad {
              padding-left: 10px;
              padding-right: 10px;
            }
            table.columns .left-text-pad,
            table.columns .text-pad-left,
            table.column .left-text-pad,
            table.column .text-pad-left {
              padding-left: 10px;
            }

            table.columns .right-text-pad,
            table.columns .text-pad-right,
            table.column .right-text-pad,
            table.column .text-pad-right {
              padding-right: 10px;
            }
            .block-grid {
              width: 100%;
              max-width: 580px;
            }
            .block-grid td {
              display: inline-block;
              padding:10px;
            }
            .two-up td {
              width:270px;
            }
            .three-up td {
              width:173px;
            }
            .four-up td {
              width:125px;
            }
            .five-up td {
              width:96px;
            }
            .six-up td {
              width:76px;
            }
            .seven-up td {
              width:62px;
            }
            .eight-up td {
              width:52px;
            }
            table.center, td.center {
              text-align: center;
            }
            h1.center,
            h2.center,
            h3.center,
            h4.center,
            h5.center,
            h6.center {
              text-align: center;
            }
            span.center {
              display: block;
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
            }
            img.center {
              margin: 0 auto;
              float: none;
            }
            .show-for-small,
            .hide-for-desktop {
              display: none;
            }
            body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td { 
              color: #222222;
              font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
              font-weight: normal; 
              padding:0; 
              margin: 0;
              text-align: left; 
              line-height: 1.3;
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
              word-break: normal;
            }
            h1 {font-size: 40px;}
            h2 {font-size: 36px;}
            h3 {font-size: 32px;}
            h4 {font-size: 28px;}
            h5 {font-size: 24px;}
            h6 {font-size: 20px;}
            body, table.body, p, td {font-size: 14px;line-height:19px;}
            p.lead, p.lede, p.leed {
              font-size: 18px;
              line-height:21px;
            }
            p { 
              margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            small {
              font-size: 10px;
            }
            a {
              color: #2ba6cb; 
              text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover { 
              color: #2795b6 !important;
            }
            a:active { 
              color: #2795b6 !important;
            }
            a:visited { 
              color: #2ba6cb !important;
            }
            h1 a, 
            h2 a, 
            h3 a, 
            h4 a, 
            h5 a, 
            h6 a {
              color: #2ba6cb;
            }
            h1 a:active, 
            h2 a:active,  
            h3 a:active, 
            h4 a:active, 
            h5 a:active, 
            h6 a:active { 
              color: #2ba6cb !important; 
            } 
            h1 a:visited, 
            h2 a:visited,  
            h3 a:visited, 
            h4 a:visited, 
            h5 a:visited, 
            h6 a:visited { 
              color: #2ba6cb !important; 
            } 
            .panel {
              background: #f2f2f2;
              border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
              padding: 10px !important;
            }
            .sub-grid table {
              width: 100%;
            }
            .sub-grid td.sub-columns {
              padding-bottom: 0;
            }
            table.button,
            table.tiny-button,
            table.small-button,
            table.medium-button,
            table.large-button {
              width: 100%;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
            table.button td,
            table.tiny-button td,
            table.small-button td,
            table.medium-button td,
            table.large-button td {
              display: block;
              width: auto !important;
              text-align: center;
              background: #2ba6cb;
              border: 1px solid #2284a1;
              color: #ffffff;
              padding: 8px 0;
            }
            table.tiny-button td {
              padding: 5px 0 4px;
            }
            table.small-button td {
              padding: 8px 0 7px;
            }
            table.medium-button td {
              padding: 12px 0 10px;
            }
            table.large-button td {
              padding: 21px 0 18px;
            }
            table.button td a,
            table.tiny-button td a,
            table.small-button td a,
            table.medium-button td a,
            table.large-button td a {
              font-weight: bold;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-size: 16px;
            }
            table.tiny-button td a {
              font-size: 12px;
              font-weight: normal;
            }
            table.small-button td a {
              font-size: 16px;
            }
            table.medium-button td a {
              font-size: 20px;
            }
            table.large-button td a {
              font-size: 24px;
            }
            table.button:hover td,
            table.button:visited td,
            table.button:active td {
              background: #2795b6 !important;
            }
            table.button:hover td a,
            table.button:visited td a,
            table.button:active td a {
              color: #fff !important;
            }
            table.button:hover td,
            table.tiny-button:hover td,
            table.small-button:hover td,
            table.medium-button:hover td,
            table.large-button:hover td {
              background: #2795b6 !important;
            }
            table.button:hover td a,
            table.button:active td a,
            table.button td a:visited,
            table.tiny-button:hover td a,
            table.tiny-button:active td a,
            table.tiny-button td a:visited,
            table.small-button:hover td a,
            table.small-button:active td a,
            table.small-button td a:visited,
            table.medium-button:hover td a,
            table.medium-button:active td a,
            table.medium-button td a:visited,
            table.large-button:hover td a,
            table.large-button:active td a,
            table.large-button td a:visited {
              color: #ffffff !important; 
            }
            table.secondary td {
              background: #e9e9e9;
              border-color: #d0d0d0;
              color: #555;
            }
            table.secondary td a {
              color: #555;
            }
            table.secondary:hover td {
              background: #d0d0d0 !important;
              color: #555;
            }
            table.secondary:hover td a,
            table.secondary td a:visited,
            table.secondary:active td a {
              color: #555 !important;
            }
            table.success td {
              background: #5da423;
              border-color: #457a1a;
            }
            table.success:hover td {
              background: #457a1a !important;
            }

            table.alert td {
              background: #c60f13;
              border-color: #970b0e;
            }
            table.alert:hover td {
              background: #970b0e !important;
            }
            table.radius td {
              -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
              -moz-border-radius: 3px;
              border-radius: 3px;
            }
            table.round td {
              -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
              -moz-border-radius: 500px;
              border-radius: 500px;
            }
            body.outlook p {
              display: inline !important;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
              table[class="body"] img {
                width: auto !important;
                height: auto !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] center {
                min-width: 0 !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .container {
                width: 95% !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .row {
                width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .wrapper {
                display: block !important;
                padding-right: 0 !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .columns,
              table[class="body"] .column {
                table-layout: fixed !important;
                float: none !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                padding-right: 0px !important;
                padding-left: 0px !important;
                display: block !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .columns,
              table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .column {
                display: table !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] table.columns td,
              table[class="body"] table.column td {
                width: 100% !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.one,
              table[class="body"] .column td.one { width: 8.333333% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.two,
              table[class="body"] .column td.two { width: 16.666666% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.three,
              table[class="body"] .column td.three { width: 25% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.four,
              table[class="body"] .column td.four { width: 33.333333% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.five,
              table[class="body"] .column td.five { width: 41.666666% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.six,
              table[class="body"] .column td.six { width: 50% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.seven,
              table[class="body"] .column td.seven { width: 58.333333% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.eight,
              table[class="body"] .column td.eight { width: 66.666666% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.nine,
              table[class="body"] .column td.nine { width: 75% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.ten,
              table[class="body"] .column td.ten { width: 83.333333% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.eleven,
              table[class="body"] .column td.eleven { width: 91.666666% !important; }
              table[class="body"] .columns td.twelve,
              table[class="body"] .column td.twelve { width: 100% !important; }
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-one,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-two,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-three,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-four,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-five,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-six,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-seven,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eight,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-nine,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-ten,
              table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eleven {
                padding-left: 0 !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] table.columns td.expander {
                width: 1px !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .right-text-pad,
              table[class="body"] .text-pad-right {
                padding-left: 10px !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .left-text-pad,
              table[class="body"] .text-pad-left {
                padding-right: 10px !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .hide-for-small,
              table[class="body"] .show-for-desktop {
                display: none !important;
              }
              table[class="body"] .show-for-small,
              table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
                display: inherit !important;
              }
            }
                table.facebook td {
                  background: #3b5998;
                  border-color: #2d4473;
                }
                table.facebook:hover td {
                  background: #2d4473 !important;
                }
                table.twitter td {
                  background: #00acee;
                  border-color: #0087bb;
                }
                table.twitter:hover td {
                  background: #0087bb !important;
                }
                table.google-plus td {
                  background-color: #DB4A39;
                  border-color: #CC0000;
                }
                table.google-plus:hover td {
                  background: #CC0000 !important;
                }
                .template-label {
                  color: #ffffff;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  font-size: 11px;
                }
                .callout .panel {
                  background: #ECF8FF;
                  border-color: #b9e5ff;
                }
                .header {
                  background: #999999;
                }
                .footer .wrapper {
                  background: #ebebeb;
                }
                .footer h5 {
                  padding-bottom: 10px;
                }
                table.columns .text-pad {
                  padding-left: 10px;
                  padding-right: 10px;
                }
                table.columns .left-text-pad {
                  padding-left: 10px;
                }
                table.columns .right-text-pad {
                  padding-right: 10px;
                }
                @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                  table[class="body"] .right-text-pad {
                    padding-left: 10px !important;
                  }
                  table[class="body"] .left-text-pad {
                    padding-right: 10px !important;
                  }
                }
             </style></head><body><table class="body"><tr><td class="center" align="center" valign="top"><center><table class="row header"><tr><td class="center" align="center"><center><table class="container"><tr><td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns"><tr><td class="six sub-columns"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></td><td class="six sub-columns last" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;"><span class="template-label">BASIC</span></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></center></td></tr></table><table class="container"><tr><td><table class="row"><tr><td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns"><tr><td><h1>Hi, '.$this->_username.'</h1><p class="lead">'.$this->_message_heading.'</p><p>'.$this->_message.'</p></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table class="row callout"><tr><td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns"><tr><td class="panel"><p>'.$this->_panel_message.'</p></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table class="row footer"><tr><td class="wrapper"><table class="six columns"><tr><td class="left-text-pad">'.$this->get_footer_left_message().'</td><td class="wrapper last">'.$this->get_footer_right_message().'</td></tr></table><table class="row"><tr><td class="wrapper last"><table class="twelve columns"><tr><td align="center"><center><p style="text-align:center;">'.$this->get_footer().'</p></center></td><td class="expander"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></center></td></tr></table></body></html>';
                }
                function sendmail(){
                    if(is_null($this->_to)){$this->_sendmail_response='"To" Email Address Not Valid or Empty '; }
                    if(is_null($this->_subject)){ $this->_sendmail_response='"Email Subject" Not Valid or Empty '; }        
                    if(mail($this->_to,$this->_subject,$this->get_message_body(), $this->get_header())){
                        $this->_sendmail_response="Test email sent at ";
                    }else{$this->_sendmail_response='Email Not Sent'; }
                }
            } ?>
```

**Is there any Alternative to my Code to Show image inline with mail?** I don't want users to right click image and download every time. Because i just want to add a logo with email.

Note:- Using Outlook 2010 to receive Email

Comment: never mind, missed the obvious part about "HTML email" :-)

Comment: The usual way is to use MIME multipart emails - are you suggesting that you don't want to go down this route?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
you can send E-Mail with an Image.

just use

```
$to = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Image sending';
$message = '<img src="" alt="Company logo" />';//use online shared url(drive or some drop box)/(www.mysite.com/image.jpg)

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi @Abdulla Check my php code attached with question

Comment: yes i tried. still i hav to right click and see image in mail client.

Comment: When i use your code I'm getting `Company logo<http://cdn.online-convert.com/images/logo-top.png>` in email